# Writing a list to a csv file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in Python and have a list of numbers that I want to write to a csv file. Say, my list is: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], and within the csv file to which I am exporting this data, I want to begin a new line every three numbers. Meaning, when I open my output file in Excel, I want it to look like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C90ET.png)

So, I essentially want to take a 9 element list and write it into a 3x3 matrix. I'm sure I must end up using the writerows command, but have not been able to find documentation of a problem similar enough to mine, so I am not sure exactly what to do with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm sorry if this question has already been asked at some point.

Comment: You can look [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-read-and-write-csv-files-in-python--cms-29907) on how to write to .csv files and the format that your list must have in order to be stored the desired way.

Comment: use python to parse the 9 element list into a list of 3 lists, and then write it

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to _first_ put your data into the form you want—a 3x3 nested list—and _then_ work out how to output it—which is then just `writerows` on that nested list.

Comment: Slicing the list by 3's has been asked, settled, and is covered in the tutorials as well.  `my_list[n:n+2] for n in range(0, len(my_list, 3)`.  Write row by row is also well-documented.  Exactly where are you stuck, that there is *no* code to post?

Answer (score 6):

slice your list into a 2D list using a comprehension, and pass that to `csv.writerows`.

Self-contained example:

```
import csv

lst = list(range(1,10))

with open("out.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f)
    cw.writerows(lst[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(lst),3))
```

creates a csv file like this:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reshape`:

```
import numpy
my_array=numpy.reshape(my_list, (3,3))
```

BTW, it should be  `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, not `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`